# Nginx - Invalid number of arguments in location directive - regex capturing group with space

Tags: nginx

Hello I've got a location directive with a case-insensitive regex match like this:

```
location ~* (/path/to/file withspace|/path/to/anotherfile) {
  return 404;
}
```

When I reload nginx I get the following error message

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "location" directive
```

After a bit of troubleshooting I found out that the problem is the whitespace in `/path/to/file withspace`.

I've then tried the following, which works

```
location ~* "/path/to/file withspace" {
  return 404;
}
```

but I'm unable to use the pipe for or-ing the paths to handle, which is an hassle to me.

So:

- why isn't the whitespace allowed?
- generally, which characters aren't allowed there and how do I handle them?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is seen by nginx when it is parsing the config, so it sees your location path as `/path/to/file`, but then when it expects the `{`, it sees the rest `withspace`.

The easiest way to do this is to use white-space meta-characters in your regular expression, so use `\s` to denote any white-space:

```
location ~* /path/to/file\swithspace {
  return 404;
}
```

If you want to be very precise about space characters but not tabs etc, use the hex character code for a space `\x20`:

```
location ~* /path/to/file\x20withspace {
  return 404;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot about a more general feature that nginx allows you to escape specific characters *anywhere* in the config just by using `\`.  This is useful when you want to include exotic characters or avoid reserved words being recognized, but it should also be possible to solve this problem:

```
location ~* /path/to/file\ withspace {
  return 404;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some link to possibly official reference of nginx about this? Furthermore, it implicitly seems that the only problematic characters are spaces (spaces, tabs...), do I get this right? Thank you

Comment: I can't find a single simple reference, it's mentioned in various places throughout the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/).  Space are probably to most common issue, yes, but also non-english characters, special symbols like `$` and nginx reserved words. I forgot that you can prefix any character with \ to stop it being interpreted (and updated the answer), so an overly cautious rule might be to quote or escape anything that is not alphanumeric or "`./_-()`"